# What is a reliable way to clean up old intermediate dependencies in yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

In case `yarn.lock` has accumulated a bunch of old intermediate dependencies, some of which may continue to linger when newer dependencies are added, what would be a reliable way to clean them up?

Answer (score 5):

Do `yarn remove` on each of the dependency packages in `package.json` (`dependencies` and `devDependencies` entries). This should remove all dependencies including all intermediate dependencies from `yarn.lock`.

P.S. A couple recommended tools:

- [`yarn-deduplicate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate)
- [`yarn-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-check)